# What is the difference between LastModifiedDate and SystemModstamp

Tags: fields

This question is fairly straight forward, but I can't it figure out.

I am using the schema browser in the IDE to query some records and the SystemModstamp is actually 1 second later than the LastModifiedDate so they are obviously different. But hence the question: what is the difference?

Comment: Here's the documentation: [Salesforce's System Fields doc page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm).

Comment: `SystemModStamp` doesn't seem to capture if the record is updated via apex trigger nor via formula field.

Comment: updated doc ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm?search_text=systemmodstamp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LastModifiedDate is the date the record was last updated by a user.
SystemModstamp is the date the record was last modified (by a user, workflow, trigger, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

If you ask nicely, salesforce will let you set the last modified by (as in, you're importing records after a merger and want to maintain the created and modified stamps from the old system).

You can't ever touch the system modstamp.